# Angular 2 expression parser and ng-init directive

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular2-template, angular2-directives

Basically I'm looking for a way to implement a counterpart to Angular 1.x `ngInit` directive.

I'm aware of `ngOnInit` hook and the fact that it is the recommended place for initialization code. I consider `ngInit` directive a quick, declarative  way to prototype or fix a component that shouldn't be generally used in well-written production code (although a developer has the right to choose what's best for him/her).

Doing something like that in `init` dummy directive

```
<p [init]="foo = 1; bar()"><p>
```

evaluates the expression more than one time and causes

> Template parse errors:
>
> Parser Error: Bindings cannot contain assignments

error.

In Angular 1.x it could be done just with

```
$parse($attrs.init)($scope)
```

How can Angular 2 parser be used and possibly extended to evaluate `foo = 1; bar()` template expression on component initialization?

Comment: Ng-init has gone the way of the dinosaur. Like you said, ngOnInit is the proper place to put initialization code, so why would they keep ng-init? What you are doing in that code is trying to *bind* init to a value, that is what square brackets indicate. But the value is an expression which, as Angular tells you, isn't supported.

Comment: I missed ng-init so much too but he is gone. RIP

Comment: @Amleonard As the question says, ng-init has its uses, even if it is misused often. I know that bracket code binds the expression which is not the desired behaviour, this is just the code that I have now. The question is how it should be done to match the desired behaviour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be achieved with a directive:

```
@Directive({ selector: '[initialize]' })
class InitializeDirective {
  @Output() initialize = new BehaviorSubject();
}
```

The expected use is:

```
<div (initialize)="initViaMethodCall(); foo = 'init via assignment'"></div>
<ng-template (initialize)="bar = 'init with no extra markup'"></template>
{{ foo }}
{{ bar }}
```

Comment: More than 3 words of English, please. All I see beside code is "It is" and "and".

Comment: It is ready to use solution for the question, and the code is pretty much self-documenting. If you have specific questions about it, feel free to ask.

Comment: thanks for the update, but I still can't get mine to work. I have the exact same `.ts` as you alongside a `div`: import { Directive, Output } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs/BehaviorSubject';

@Directive({ selector: '[initialize]' })
export class InitDirective {
  @Output() initialize = new BehaviorSubject(100);
}  **AND** <div (initialize)="trigger('set-form', { name: 'basics', section: basics }); foo = 'AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA'">
      ++++{{foo}}++++
    </div>

Comment: How is the `@Output` property `initialize` firing/`.emit()`ing?

Comment: Here's a working example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-initialize-directive

Comment: Glad it worked for you. It doesn't need `emit`, that's the reason why `BehaviourSubject` was used instead of `EventEmitter`. `initialize` is dummy event, it's never fired. It's there only to evaluate an expression.

Answer (score 4):

Just a Workaround ( [**Plunker Demo**](http://plnkr.co/edit/fDYIqPqZzLhtDYjAZnuh?p=preview) ), see **estus**'s answer for a solution

### `init` Directive:

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[init]',
  inputs: ['init']
})
export class InitDir {
  init;

  ngOnChanges() {     // `ngOnInit` if you want it to run just once
    if(this.init){
      let iife = function(str){ return eval(str); }.call(this.init[0], this.init[1]);
    }
  }
}
```

### Usage:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <div>
      <h2 [init]="[this, 'this.name = 1; this.bar();']">Hello {{name}}</h2>
    </div>
  `,
})
export class App {
  constructor() {
    this.name = 'Angular2 (Release Candidate!)'
  }

  bar() {
    alert('Yo Bar!');
  }
}
```

Comment: eval is evil. It is is supposed that this will be implemented with Angular's own parser, that's what it is for. Just not sure how.

Comment: There is obviously a thing like that in A2, just because it does expression parsing. `@angular/compiler` [contains a class that is responsible for that](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/modules/%40angular/compiler/src/expression_parser/parser.ts). It may be still undocumented but it is there.