# Understanding *ngIf expression

Tags: angular

**Background**

In my template file I am looping through some data from a http response.

```
<div *ngFor="let method of paymentMethods">
```

Within that loop I am outputting

```
method?.payment_profile_id
```

Now inside of that loop I want to show one of two elements based on the value of `method?.payment_profile_id`.

I am trying to express this inside of a `*ngIf`

```
*ngIf="defaultPayment = method?.payment_profile_id"
```

Or,

```
*ngIf="defaultPayment != method?.payment_profile_id"
```

But when trying to do that, I get a parser error,

> Parser Error: Bindings cannot contain assignments at column 18 in
>   [defaultPayment = method?.payment_profile_id]

**Question**

What is the proper way to write this expression?

Comment: Use a double equals, not a single, `==`, a single `=` is an assignment operator, not an equality operator.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular 2 expression parser and ng-init directive](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39210257/angular-2-expression-parser-and-ng-init-directive)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are doing assignment with `=` but it should be `==` or `===` if you want comparison.

Answer (score 0):

As it is clear from the error you got

> Bindings cannot contain assignments at column 18 in [defaultPayment = method?.payment_profile_id]

`*ngIf` (binding) is just used to check and return `Boolean(true/false)` to the template you cannot assign any value between *ngIf. so to check the equality you either have to use `==` or `===` not `=` so the correct syntax is as stated in above answer.

```
*ngIf="defaultPayment == method?.payment_profile_id"
```