# Not understanding use of template variables in *ngIf statement

Tags: angular, typescript, variables, angular-ng-if

my objective is to eventually make a setting where the user can change the number of rows while looking at the catalog (spiritwoodart.com).  I didn't even get past the first stage of fiddling when I ran into a problem.  Guessing its a fundamental misunderstanding.  Having trouble finding help (i.e. my search sucks: "why cant i put a template variables in ngif statement").  Please let me know if more info is needed. Thanks for any and all insights, or even flames for my newbiness.

So, when I change

this:

```
            <div *ngIf="(i+1) % n === 0"
                class="w-100"></div>
```

to this:

or this:

```
            <div #n='3' *ngIf="(i+1) % n === 0"
                class="w-100"></div>
```

or even this:

```
            <div *ngIf="(i+1) % {{3}} === 0"
                class="w-100"></div>
```

I get an error that looks like this:

```
compiler.js:485 Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:
There is no directive with "exportAs" set to "3" ("
                        [cart]="cart"></product-card>
                </div>
                <div [ERROR ->]#n='3' *ngIf="(i+1) % n === 0"
                    class="w-100"></div>
            </ng-container>
"): ng:///AppModule/ProductsComponent.html@12:21
```

context-template:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-3">
        <product-filter [category]="category"></product-filter>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
        <div class="row"
            *ngIf="cart$ | async as cart">
            <ng-container *ngFor="let p of filteredProducts; let i = index">
                <div class="col">
                    <product-card [product]="p"
                        [cart]="cart"></product-card>
                </div>
                <div *ngIf="(i+1) % 3 === 0"
                    class="w-100"></div>
            </ng-container>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

context-component:

```
import { Cart } from './../models/cart';
import { CartService } from './../cart.service';
import { Product } from './../models/product';
import { ProductService } from './../product.service';
import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/switchMap';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs/Subscription';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-products',
  templateUrl: './products.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./products.component.css']
})
export class ProductsComponent implements OnInit {
  products: Product[] = [];
  filteredProducts: Product[] = [];
  category: string; // keep this field in this class in order to initialize it... then delegate it out
  cart$: Observable<Cart>;

  constructor(
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private productService: ProductService,
    private cartService: CartService
  ) {}

  async ngOnInit() {
    this.cart$ = await this.cartService.getCart();
    this.populateProducts();
  }

  private populateProducts() {
    this.productService
      .getAll()
      .switchMap(products => {
        this.products = products;
        return this.route.queryParamMap;
      })
      .subscribe(params => {
        this.category = params.get('category'); // initializing category field
        this.applyFilter();
      });
  }

  private applyFilter() {
    // setting the filtered products array
    this.filteredProducts = this.category
      ? this.products.filter(p => p.category === this.category)
      : this.products;
  }
}
```

Comment: Well, then don't change the expression. The one in the first snippet is correct. All you need of a public `n` property in your **component**.

Comment: <div #n='3' *ngIf="(i+1) % n === 0"
                class="w-100"></div>       this one is correct?  and then  just declare n as public? cool

Comment: this       <div *ngIf="(i+1) % n === 0"
                class="w-100"></div>

Comment: No, it's not, as the compiler tells you: "There is no directive with "exportAs" set to "3"".

Comment: why did you have to make it so simple!? haha No but seriously theres no way to use template input or reference variables here? just for fun

Comment: The thing you're trying to do isn't supported natively exactly because it's 'for fun'. ng-init was proven to generally be an antipattern in AngularJS, so it wasn't included in Angular. Use component class for setting up a constant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`#` is [template reference variable](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#!#ref-vars). It defers to DOM element and cannot be used like that.

`ng-init` directive exists in AngularJS and serves this purpose, but it doesn't exist in Angular, primarily because it is prone to be misused. It's possible to recreate it, as shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39864403/3731501).

A workaround is to use a structural directive. A typical workaround for **truthy** value is `ngIf` structural directive:

```
<ng-container *ngIf="3; let n">
  <div *ngIf="(i+1) % n === 0">
    ...
```

It won't work if the value is **falsy**, because nested component won't be compiled. More universal workaround that supports falsy values is custom `ngVar` structural directive, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43172992/3731501).

Answer (score 0):

For fellow newbs like me here's what I did for now with JB's advice...
Thanks JB. And I hope this helps someone else.

just a few changes...

template:

```
<div class="row">
        <input #myInput (change)="changeColumnNumber(myInput.value)" type="number">
</div>
```

component:

```
  n = 4;
```

Full context:

template:

```
    <div class="row">
        <input #myInput (change)="changeColumnNumber(myInput.value)" type="number">
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-3">
        <product-filter [category]="category"></product-filter>
    </div>

    <div class="col">
        <div class="row"
            *ngIf="cart$ | async as cart">
            <ng-container *ngFor="let p of filteredProducts; let i = index">
                <div class="col">
                    <product-card [product]="p"
                        [cart]="cart"></product-card>
                </div>
                <div *ngIf="(i+1) % n === 0"
                    class="w-100"></div>
            </ng-container>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

component:

```
import { Cart } from './../models/cart';
import { CartService } from './../cart.service';
import { Product } from './../models/product';
import { ProductService } from './../product.service';
import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/switchMap';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs/Subscription';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-products',
  templateUrl: './products.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./products.component.css']
})
export class ProductsComponent implements OnInit {
  products: Product[] = [];
  filteredProducts: Product[] = [];
  category: string; // keep this field in this class in order to initialize it... then delegate it out
  cart$: Observable<Cart>;
  n = 4;


  constructor(
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private productService: ProductService,
    private cartService: CartService,

  ) {}

  async ngOnInit() {
    this.cart$ = await this.cartService.getCart();
    this.populateProducts();
  }

  private populateProducts() {
    this.productService
      .getAll()
      .switchMap(products => {
        this.products = products;
        return this.route.queryParamMap;
      })
      .subscribe(params => {
        this.category = params.get('category'); // initializing category field
        this.applyFilter();
      });
  }

  private applyFilter() {
    // setting the filtered products array
    this.filteredProducts = this.category
      ? this.products.filter(p => p.category === this.category)
      : this.products;
  }

  changeColumnNumber(value) {
    console.log(value);
    this.n = value;
    console.log(this.n);
  }
}
```